# Facebook API - How to get content of specific comment using Facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been asked to create a Facebook app that reads a Facebook user's news feed.

For now I have found out how to read a Facebook user's news feed via the /[user-id]/home path. My issues is that I don't know how to get the content of a user's comment on a video/photo etc.. For example, when I call the /[user-id]/home path I can see that a user (friend of [user-id]) has made a comment on a "video-post". I can see the "news ID" of the friend's "action" as '[user-id-of-friend]_[id-of-post-commented-on]', but how can I get the ID of the actual comment, which I need to be able to retrieve the content of the actual comment? The comment ID should look something like '[post-id]_[comment-id]' if I am not mistaken. I need the comment ID to get the detailed information about the comment when making a call to the /[post-id]_[comment-id] path.

A possible, slow and tedious, workaround would be to get all the comments of the "video-post" (calling /[post-id]/comments) and iterate through all the comments until I find the comment of the specific user.

Comment: Are you using read_stream permission? And if so you are aware that you will not be approved for that permission?

Comment: @WizKid - Yes I am using the read_stream permission and yes I am aware that the app most likely will not get approved. The app is for research purposes which is why the researcher (the guy I am creating the app for) think he can get approved despite the limited use statement in the Facebook documentation regarding the read_stream permission. Therefore the researcher has asked me to build the app no matter if it gets approved or not - hence I hope for someone to answer my question.

Comment: @WizKid - Do you know if there is an alternative way of crawling a Facebook user's news feed?

Comment: If you are not going to make it public just use read_stream.